# Installing a software remotely on windows is failing. But, when logged into the machine, everything works fine

Tags: ruby, windows, powershell, chef-infra

I'm trying to install SQL Express on Windows 2012R2 server remotely either using **"windows_package/powershell_script"** chef resources. I tried executing the script I have after remoting into the machine, it installs fine.

But, when I try to execute it remotely using Chef/Powershell, it's neither installing the software nor giving out an error. Is this because of configuration issues?

Currently when I attempt to use the below resources, nothing is installing:

```
1. Windows_package:
windows_package 'Install SQL Express' do
  source 'C:\\Folder\\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe'
  action :install
  options '/QUIET /SAPWD="C0mp!ex" /ConfigurationFile="C:\\Folder\\sql_express.ini" /TCPENABLED="1" /SECURITYMODE="SQL"'
end

2. powershell_script:
powershell_script 'Install SQL Express' do
  code <<-EOH
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope Process -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
  Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force
  C:\\Folder\\sql_express.ps1
  EOH
end
```

And the Powershell script that I used is:

```
$app = 'C:\\Folder\\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe'
$myarg = '/QUIET /SAPWD="C0mp!ex" /ConfigurationFile="C:\\Folder\\sql_express.ini" /TCPENABLED="1" /SECURITYMODE="SQL"'

Start-Process $app -ArgumentList $myarg
Start-Sleep 300
```

The Powershell script when ran on the machine, it works fine. Why is the script working fine when executed on the machine and not remotely?

Please let me know if I need to make any changes to the script or resources to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some issues with certain installers and the default security restrictions on WinRM. We're working on moving more stuff to use the winrm-elevated gem but it's been a long-running project. Usually a simple fix is to run the install through a scheduled task instead of directly.

Comment: Because of the problems described by coderanger I'm using Powershell DSC (which is supported in 2012R2) for these kind of remote installations (this works perfectly)

Comment: I tried using the Windows scheduled task also. The task is getting created on the machine and it shows running. But, it is not installing the software. @coderan

Comment: @dheeraj - I'm not familiar with Chef (besides knowing what it is and does) but it should be possible. DSC requires you to declare a config in a .mof file (you can generate them with a "configuration" script in Powershell). Invoking them in powershell using the push functionality is one command which basicly executes locally (it uses CIM if I remember correctly) : Start-DSCConfiguration with some parameters. Reading some basic articles about Powershell DSC should get you started in no time.